# Passing argument with ">=" to argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I was wondering if it's possible to pass the argument greater than or equal a python script which then uses argparse to parse all the arguments? for example:

```
python foo.py -a bob -d >= 12
```

With the `>` symbol I always get the error message:

```
foo.py: error: argument -d/--min number : expected at least one argument
```

Valid inputs would either be `=3` or `>=3`.

Comment: Can't you just put it in quotes? like `-d ">= 12"`

Comment: This would be pretty messy, the script is getting called by another app and its pretty difficult to get that app to add quotes around the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't argparse, it's that `>` has a special meaning on the command line (channeling output into a file). You need to ensure that the value is treated as plain string by the shell:

```
python foo.py -a bob -d '>=' 12
```

or:

```
python foo.py -a bob -d '>= 12'
```

(Depending on whether `>=` and `12` are supposed to be two arguments or one.)

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without quotes ?The script is getting called by a another app?

Comment: If your app is executing a shell command containing a bare `>` without wanting it to mean "redirect stdout to file", then it's doing it wrong. It *must* be quoted if you want it to have the meaning of the plain character ">".

Comment: doh! thanks for that, your absolutely correct. Completely forgot about the pipe so it mast be adding quotes by default